# Нужно сделать доступным сервер node js пользователям не из локальной сети

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, сеть, socket.io

Не пойму как сделать сервер доступным в глобальной сети *(не в локальной)*, а именно чат из [примера на socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Делал это так:

1. Открывал порт 3000 в роутере *(он же используется в примере)*.

   [image: скриншот настроек роутера]
2. Брал ip компьютера, на котором запущен сам сервер, на сайте 2ip и соединял с портом 3000.
3. Но в итоге сайт не загружался и в хроме была ошибка 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'. Да и на 2ip писало, что порт 3000 закрыт.

Так же, думая, что проблема с портами, пытался открыть их через µTorrent. Но сайт так же не был доступен в глобальной сети и не работал в локальной (сайт загружался, но была только надпись 'invalid request', а в консоли пишет 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (ERROR)').

Хотелось бы понять, что делаю не так). Да и вообще... возможно ли это сделать?)

Comment: https://modulus.io/  [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)  https://c9.io/

Comment: Возможно, дело в NAT провайдера?

Comment: Порой проще взять что-то вроде [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) и не парится.

Comment: Список хостингов для NodeJS серверов: [Список](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Node-Hosting)